# Multiple computers sharing one TFS workspace

Tags: tfs, tfvc

We've got a pair of terminal servers for a team of developers to share and I would like to configure TFS so that each user's workspace can be mapped to a network drive and available on both terminal servers.

Basically, I want it to not matter which server they've on, they'll have the same local workspace on either location.

As far as I can tell, that's not possible since local workspaces are tied to the computer name and I've been told by my admin that I'm not allowed to use server workspaces.

Is there a way to do this with TFS 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each workspace will be used by one person at any given time and the paths will always be the same, you [could use the updateComputerName option to tell the server that workspace is now on a different computer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/03/03/update-workspace.aspx).

If you want to allow simultaneous access to a workspace across different machines, that would cause significant problems with corruption of the workspace.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I do not need to share workspaces between users so this will technically work.  It's the only solution I could come up with as well.  I was hoping though that I wouldn't have to swap it between machines like that.  We tried scripting it out but ran into more challenges and ultimately decided that users should drop their workspaces after their done with their project and start fresh often.